# how would i manage to install python's boto library on shared hosting?

Tags: python

how would i manage to install python's boto library on shared hosting?

Comment: What kind of access do you have to your shared hosting? Can you access the box via SSH? What type of OS is on the box (Windows, Linux)?

Comment: linux os. yes, i have ssh access

Comment: i just asked my hosting provider and he installed boto within minutes. great hosting

Answer (score 2):

Why install virtualenv? I would try:

`easy_install boto`

or

`pip install boto`

pip and easy_install are python tools for installing other packages. Who is your hosting service? If they have these utilities, using them would be the easiest route.

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/

That link will tell you how to install pip and easy_install (because easy_install is part of the setup tools package) under a system that uses apt. Otherwise, look up instructions specific to your system.

Comment: If it's shared hosting, he's unlikely to have access to install packages globally.

Comment: You can also use easy_install and pip to install locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you can SSH in, then I would install [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and install bobo in a virtual Python environment. It's surprisingly easy and fully featured.